# Making AJAX POST request to Servlet fails

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, post

From my client side code, I am making an AJAX call to my servlet. If I use GET as request method. Everything works and I get response back. But when I send request as POST, servlet fails to send the response. From log I found out that in servlet "request" object is null when made ajax call with POST. According to this post: 
[Servlet response to AJAX request is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693457/servlet-response-to-ajax-request-is-empty) , I'm setting headers for same-origin policy.

Below is my code for reference:

```
function aimslc_ajaxCall(url,callback, postParams){
  var xmlhttp = null
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    eval( callback+"("+xmlhttp.responseText+")" );
    }
  }

  if(postParams!=null && typeof postParams!="undefined" ){
            xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send(postParams);
  }else{
            xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
```

Servlet Code:

```
 public void doProcess (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      logger.info("doProcess::start..."+request.getQueryString());
      response.setHeader("P3P","CP='NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTR STP IND DEM'");
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true");
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST, GET");
 }
```

Throws a null exception on request.getQueryString()

Comment: Check your if statement in ajax, Seems like it always executes xmlhttp.send() without any payload. Try to put alert to check which conditional option is being chooses every time.

Comment: Actually if there are no params, I make a request with GET method. Edited code to make it more clear

Answer (score 3):

if you do a post all the data is in the request body, not on the url.  From [here](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29) you see that `getQueryString` only gets the stuff on the url.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023718/how-to-retreive-raw-post-data-from-httpservletrequest-in-java) for how to get the request body.

Also, if your data is name/value pairs, you might want to use [getParameter](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) and associated methods.

If the request is null, I ask do you implement `doPost` on your servlet?

Comment: This makes some sense. I do have doPost(). Following on the same question - what's difference between "request.getAttribute()" and "request.getParameter()". In servlet that I m using, request.getAttribut() is used to retrieve request parameters. This seems to work for GET but not for POST.

Comment: getParameter is used to get parameters of the from key=val.  get attribute gets the request attributes, which are not the same.  You want to use getParameter and associated methods

Comment: @indusBull: the `HttpServletRequest` has `getParameter()` and `getAttribute()` methods. Which one do you *think* that it returns the request **parameter**? Try to think logically...

Comment: @BalusC My logical conclusion before asking that question was getParameter(). But the servlet (written by some well exp person) that I'm accessing has getAttributes() methods.That confused me.

Comment: It's just been used to get request **attributes**. Not parameters.

Comment: I've opened an another question to discuss the difference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266338/why-does-getattribute-in-httpservletrequest-works-for-get-mothod-but-not-for-po